# Gingerbread house- bad face render

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image: render issue]Using blender 4.0, working through gingerbread house tutorial. Have a face with just scales and subdivision mod. Render in Cycles and it distorts the face badly. What am I missing?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It was the mirror modifier. I had 2 axis’s selected after I did the mirror.